# Наследование в Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста. Читаю книгу по asp.net, и попадается такая вот фраза:

> В следующем коде приведенный ранее пример переписан так, чтобы он проверял литеральные элементы управления и при их наличии приводил базовый объект Control к типу LiteralControl для извлечения связанного текста

А вот, собственно, сам код:

```
foreach (Control control in Page.Controls) 
{ 
  Response.Write(control.GetType().ToString() + " - <b>" + control.ID +"</b><br />");

  if (control is LiteralControl) 
  {
    // Отобразить содержимое литерального элемента 
    // управления (включая пробелы). 
    Response.Write("*** Text: " + ((LiteralControl)control).Text + "<br />"); 
  } 
}
Response.Write("<hr>");
```

Но дело не в коде, я, может быть, не понимаю формулировку, но КАК можно приводить БАЗОВЫЙ тип к ПРОИЗВОДНОМУ? Если я правильно понимаю, то можно привести ПРОИЗВОДНЫЙ к БАЗОВОМУ (так как производный включает в себя базовый), но не наоборот.
Господа, где я не прав, подскажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно и довольно часто используются ключевые слова [AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) и [IS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) в коллекциях разных объектов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего особенного. Page.Controls содержит экземпляры класса Control, каждый из которых может быть (а точнее, обязан быть) экземпляром не самого Control, а какого-то из его наследников. Вполне логично, что если control is LiteralControl == true, то этот контрол можно привести от базового класса Control к наследнику LiteralControl без каких-либо проблем и работать с ним уже как с LiteralControl (от обычного Control толку маловато). 
Само по себе обявление Control[] Controls предполагает, что каждый элемент коллекции Controls обязан быть наследником Control и, соответственно, иметь весь набор членов, присущих классу COntrol - сказать что-то более о классах формы нельзя, поскольку неизвестно заранее, какими именно они будут

Небольшой пример (впрочем, в данном примере это довольно-таки хреновый подход):

```
var array = new object[] { "qwerty", 10, true, 10.5 };
foreach (var item in array)
{
    if(item is string)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is string", item);
    else if(item is int)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is int", item);
    else if (item is bool)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is bool", item);
    else if (item is double)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is double", item);
}
```

То есть технически ничего невозможного в приведении от базового класса к потомку нет. Однако это далеко не всегда оправдано

Comment: О, спасибо большое, дошло. Просто как-то в книге очень запутанно выходит.